# Android onActivityResult never called from DialogFragment in Fragment

Tags: android, camera, fragment, onactivityresult, dialogfragment

I want to display `Dialog` for choosing between opening the `Camera` / `Gallery` in a `Fragment`.

After a `Button` is pressed, I show a custom `DialogFragment` (this `DialogFragment` is an `inner` `class`inside the `Fragment`).

```
public static class AddPictureDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_picture_dialog, container, false);
        getDialog().setTitle("New Picture");

        Button openCameraButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.open_camera_button);
        openCameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("","Open Camera Option Selected");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                getDialog().dismiss();

            }
        });

        Button openGalleryButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.open_gallery_button);
        openGalleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("","Open Gallery Option Selected");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

After one opcion is selected, the `Camera` / `Gallery` is initialised, but after making / selecting a picture, the method `onActivityResult` is never called.

Here is the code where I create the `DialogFragment`:

```
FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    AddPictureDialogFragment addPictureDialogFragment = new AddPictureDialogFragment();
    addPictureDialogFragment.show(fm, getTag());
```

The weird thing is that if I create the `DialogFragment` directly in the `Fragment` without using the `DialogFragment` it works...

I have also tried this, when creating the `DialogFragment`:

```
addPictureDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 1);
```

and this, when initialising the `camera` `Intent`:

```
Button openCameraButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.open_camera_button);
    openCameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("","Open Camera Option Selected");
            getDialog().dismiss();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), 1, intent); 
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);         
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
private void showAddImageDialog() {
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    AddPictureDialogFragment addPictureDialogFragment = new AddPictureDialogFragment();
    addPictureDialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, REQUEST_CAMERA);
    addPictureDialogFragment.show(fm, getTag());
}



public static class AddPictureDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_picture_dialog, container, false);
        getDialog().setTitle("New Picture");


        Button openCameraButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.open_camera_button);
        openCameraButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("","Open Camera Option Selected");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                getTargetFragment().startActivityForResult(intent, getTargetRequestCode());
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });

        Button openGalleryButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.open_gallery_button);
        openGalleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("","Open Gallery Option Selected");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                getTargetFragment().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"), SELECT_FILE);
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your main activity overwrite onActivityResult method as follows.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
     if(fragment!=null)
        fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Sometimes the fragment might be destroyed but the reference might persist and hence the if(fragment!=null) check.

Comment: Thanks@Ragesh Ramesh. Yes I know that, but I want it in the 'Fragment', not in the 'Activity'

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice that. Updating my answer

Comment: it works 99%. The method `onActivityResult ` now is called in the `Fragment` but the `requestCode` is wrong. I voted up your answer anyway, thanks for your time and your effort :)

Comment: Strange - what request code did you send and what are you getting.

Answer (score 2):

Please write this code in your Main Actvity.

```
 // In your activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        System.out.println("onActivityResult Main Activity");
        for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This part is very simple

Just call `startActivityForResult(intent,constant);`
in you fragment class

override the `onActivityResult` in activity and don't remove  `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

also override the `onActivityResult` in fragment class

In activity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "activity result called");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

In fragment

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "fragment result called");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==constant){
        Logger.d(TAG, "got result");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Override onActivityResult in parent Activity i.e. parent of all fragment

Override this method on your Main activity :

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    TestFrag demoFragment = (TestFrag) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("test");
    demoFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

after your fragment activity result call